# Object.assign on mongoose model is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I got newTask is not a function error when I trying to use object assign.

```
let newTask = new Task()

    /*newTask = Object.assign({}, params); won't work */

    newTask.language = params.language // working

    newTask.save((err, resp) => {
        if(err){
            return res.json({success: false, msg: err })
        }

        callback(err, resp)
    })
```

I have many more params need to be added to newTask, but why in this case object assign won't work?

Comment: Why would you think this would work? All you need do here is `let newTask = Task(params)` anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn oh really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning newTask to an empty object with just the params.

Try this instead:

```
let newTask = new Task()

Object.assign(newTask, params)

newTask.save((err, resp) => {
    if(err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: err })
    }

    callback(err, resp)
})
```

This way newTask properties get overridden with the properties from the params object.